# Tikz: how to set exact position of node

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I have made following tikz picture:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{center}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[->, >=stealth', auto, semithick, node distance=3cm]
    \tikzstyle{every state}=[fill=white,draw=black,thick,text=black,scale=1]
    \node[state]    (A)                     {\textborn};
    \node[state]    (B)[right of=A]   {$\diamond_0$};
    \node[state]    (D)[right of=B]   {$...$};
    \node[state]    (E)[right of=D]   {$\diamond_5$};
    \node[state]    (C)[below of=B]   {\textdied};
    \path
    (A) edge[loop left]         node{$1-i_x-q_x^a$} (A)
    (A) edge[bend right,below]  node{$i_x$} (B)
    (A) edge[bend right,left]   node{$q_{x}^a$} (C)
    (B) edge[bend right,below]  node{$r_{x,x}$} (A)
    (C) edge[loop below,below]          node{$1$}   (C)
    %-------------%
    (B) edge[below]     node{$1-r_{x-1,x}-q_{x-1,x}^i$} (D)
    edge[right]     node{$q_{x,x}^i$}   (C)
    (D) edge[bend right = 40,above]     node{$r_{j,x}$} (A)
    (D) edge[bend left]     node{$q_{x-j,x}^i$} (C)
    %-------------%
    (D) edge[below]     node{$1-r_{x-4,x}-q_{x-4,x}^i$} (E)
    (E) edge[loop right]            node{$1-q_{x}^i-r_{x}$} (E)
    edge[bend left]     node{$q_{x}^i$} (C)
    (E) edge[bend right = 50, above]    node{$r_{x}$} (A);
    %\node[above=0.5cm] (A){Patch G};
    %\draw[red] ($(D)+(-1.5,0)$) ellipse (2cm and 3.5cm)node[yshift=3cm]{Patch H};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
```

As you can see, the arrows from `\diamond_0` to `\dots` and from `\dots` to `\diamond_5` are too small for texts. Has someone a neat idea without having to reposition the whole tikz graphic? Thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436/184389) You can locally redefine the `node distance` property. For example, in the definition of node `(D)`, you can add `node distance = 5cm` to the options which will locally overwrite the default `3cm` defined in the `tikzpicture` options.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

[image]

You should use `positioning` library with it syntax (which determined distance between nodes), reduce edge labels font size (to `\footnotesize`, for example)
and for edge labels use `quotes` library:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, automata,
                calc,
                positioning,
                quotes}


\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2cm and 3cm,
   arr/.style = {-Stealth, semithick},
every edge/.append style = {-Stealth, semithick},
every edge quotes/.style = {auto, font=\footnotesize }
                        ]
   \begin{scope}[nodes=state]
\node               (A) {\textborn};
\node[right=of A]   (B) {$\diamond_0$};
\node[right=of B]   (D) {$\dots$};
\node[right=of D]   (E) {$\diamond_5$};
\node[below=of B]   (C) {\textdied};
    \end{scope}
\path   (A) edge[loop left, "$1-i_x-q_x^a$"]    (A)
        (A) edge[bend right, "$i_x$"]           (B)
        (A) edge[bend right, "$q_{x}^a$"]       (C)
        (B) edge[bend right,"$r_{x,x}$"]        (A)
        (C) edge[loop below,"$1$"]              (C)
%-------------%
        (B) edge["$1-r_{x-1,x}-q_{x-1,x}^i$"]   (D)
           edge["$q_{x,x}^i$"]   (C)
        (D) edge[bend right=40,"$r_{j,x}$"]     (A)
        (D) edge[bend left]     node{$q_{x-j,x}^i$} (C)
%-------------%
        (D) edge["$1-r_{x-4,x}-q_{x-4,x}^i$"]       (E)
        (E) edge[loop right,"$1-q_{x}^i-r_{x}$"]    (E)
            edge[bend left,"$q_{x}^i$"]         (C)
        (E) edge[bend right=50,"$r_{x}$"]       (A);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Note: don't use deprecated `\tikzstyle`, rather as option to `tikzpicture` or use `\tikzset`.